# why on cassandra - The key of the entities was not migrated?

Tags: cassandra, database-schema

I am new on Cassandra,

The "hash_key" is different than the "key_desc_id" and I have some issues because of that.  Any help with what should i do to fix this issue?

```
 id            | name
---------------+----------------------------------------------
 1638430493227 | default_cd77c646-cfa4-40b9-9136-5ce83fc586c9
 1638430494138 |                                  k2_hash_key

 
 select id,key_desc_id from k2view_cc.entity;
 
 id                                                               | key_desc_id
------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------
 D54C994CF3CBDA1F70E37853B07388D0C65E824F1BDF3D4F83731513EB8A5399 | 1572012180007
 DD5C1E2D9395CA6B1B5ABDF87C03392493F03328F37830045749EA1AE725AF91 | 1572012180007
 3467EA971FC018EB561F07F57547CF17E618B76D93B4F8471280C3CF8FB32D58 | 1572012180007
 EB4A8D07DF41EDDB49D530BE39B8D8850AFF7D108787CE1EF46EE27D00E99E57 | 1572012180007
 AB92F2C90E3337EED0B68B2EC1B56B6FA45A9461C711406B7ED01BE7B29F75EE | 1572012180007
 9BC6D9862B68C8AE810CC1A00BFF87ADF6A95A262C98987780807D458682330C | 1572012180007
 AFE8B598517CCFC09E71DF10417DAC3B1002731F43334CA6872BC4CEA9A07D75 | 1572012180007
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here...I see two tables.  Which one are you trying to fix?

Comment: Also, what is the Primary Key definition?  Can you edit your question with that?